# SQL how to get columns subtract value based on time stamp

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have a table _event and values inserted as below:

```
create table _event ( event_type integer not null, value integer not null, [time] datetime not null, unique(event_type, time) );


insert into _event values(2, 5, '2015-05-09 12:42:00');

insert into _event values(4, -42, '2015-05-09 13:19:57');

insert into _event values(2, 2, '2015-05-09 14:48:30');

insert into _event values(2, 7, '2015-05-09 12:54:39');

insert into _event values(3, 16, '2015-05-09 13:19:57');

insert into _event values(3, 20, '2015-05-09 15:01:09');
```

I need to print the result as below:

Answer:

> `event_type   value
>
>        2            -5
>
>        3             4`

It should take the rows with same event_type order by time and subtract the values .

For eg:
Table:

```
event_type  value   time
2   5   2015-05-09 12:42:00.000
4   -42 2015-05-09 13:19:57.000
2   2   2015-05-09 14:48:30.000
2   7   2015-05-09 12:54:39.000
3   16  2015-05-09 13:19:57.000
3   20  2015-05-09 15:01:09.000
```

Select only event_type 2 and 3 rows.Order by time stamp.So for event_type :2

```
event_type  value   time
2              5    2015-05-09 12:42:00.000
2              2    2015-05-09 14:48:30.000
2              7    2015-05-09 12:54:39.000
```

The result will pick values 2 ,7 based on top timestamp and subtract:

```
event_type       value  
     2            -5
```

Hope it is clear.Kindly help me.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear to me how you arriving at those values in your expected output.  Also, are you using SQL Server or SQLite, they are two very different databases.

Comment: Hi,the result should take only rows with event_type value same and subtract the values :For eg: event type :2 and value is -5(2-7)

Comment: Hi i edited the question..hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach below first assigns row numbers to each `event_type` group.  Then, it uses a pivot query to identify and subtract the latest event from the second latest event.

```
SELECT
    event_type,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN value END) -
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN value END) AS value
FROM
(
    SELECT event_type, value, [time],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY [time] DESC) rn
    FROM _event
) t
WHERE rn <= 2
GROUP BY
    event_type
ORDER BY
    event_type;
```

[image]

### Demo